# Not working leaderboard Google Play Service

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

added a leaderboard to the Google Play Service. Resources are added, authorization is working, adding a record is working. But when use ShowLeaderboardUI() only shows the name of the highscore table, but there are no highscores. Help pls ;(

CODE Ads Init:

```
public class AdsInitialize : MonoBehaviour
{
 public static AdsInitialize instance = null;
 private string LEADER_BOARD = "******";
 public Text _text;

 private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });
            PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
            PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
            Social.localUser.Authenticate(success =>
            {
                if (success)
                {
                    _text.text = "Auth working";
                }
                else
                {
                    _text.text = "Auth not working";
                }
            });
        }
        else if (instance != this)
        { 
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    public void ShowLeaderBoard()
    {
        //Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI(LEADER_BOARD);     
    }
}
```

Write highscores:

```
 Social.ReportScore(_time, AdsInitialize.instance.LEADER_BOARD, (bool success) => {
   if (success)
   {
       _text.text = "ReportScore working";
   }
   else
   {
        _text.text = "ReportScore not working";
   }
});
```

Show leaderboard in menu (this method is hanging on button):

```
public void ShowLeaderBoard()
{
    AdsInitialize.instance.ShowLeaderBoard();
}
```

Comment: As per this site's tagging guidelines, please avoid putting tags in your question title. Use the tagging system instead (as you already have done).

Answer (score 1):

You need update your Google Play Games at phone